# What VSCode extension did this?

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense, extension-methods

Before I reset my pc I was using visual studio code and python a lot Until after I reset it I forgot to transfer the settings over and so I lost all my extensions. I now cannot find an extension. (I was using it before). The extension pretty much when I type "pr" then I click tab to auto complete it. Instead of it just auto-completing "Print" it auto-completed the brackets and speech marks and then it made it so i could automatically type and it would be in the speech marks (if this makes sense). My question is do any of you know what the extension is called.

Comment: This is just intellisense as far as I can tell

Comment: ...and intellisense is built-in, so perhaps all you have to do is enable it via some preferences setting.

Comment: I know its something to do with that but I just cant seem to find it i was wondering if its an extention if so what is the name of it .

Comment: I fount autosurround but I cant find the option to say both.

Comment: @StuartLittle, it seems you are looking for the code snippets in vs code, there have some built in snippets and we can also try to install extensions to includes more snippets, please check this doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets